# Reloading page with another HTML using Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I'm trying to load a new HTML page after the user logs in.

My login is currently:

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate(
  'local', {
     session:false,
}), getToken); // callback function
```

This returns a token to the client, which is used to call /mainPage.

```
app.get('/mainPage', (req, res) => {
  console.log("/mainPage reached");
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/mainpage.html');
})
```

I'm not getting any errors, and I'm getting `/mainPage reached` in my console, but it's not reloading the page. I'm assuming it's because there is already another HTML page present. How do I load a new page?

I've tried using successRedirect in passport.authenticate, but I don't think it works since I have another function that is called after it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't in my server code, it was with the client. I wasn't doing anything with my xml response, so I needed to use document.write() to reload the page.